# Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition - But tables match?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure where I'd like to drop a table from when the process had previously run, recreate the table and then do a join, however I'm met with "Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition." when executing the procedure. It works when I manually drop the table, then create it and execute the procedure. I'm confused because it would seem the columns match in the insert statement.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SYSOBJECTS WHERE ID =OBJECT_ID('TBL_OPERATION_BY_DAY'))
BEGIN
DROP TABLE TBL_OPERATION_BY_DAY

--CREATES TBL HOLDING EVERY FLIGHT BY DAY

CREATE TABLE TBL_OPERATION_BY_DAY
(
    AIRLINE_CODE VARCHAR(02),
    FLIGHT_NUMBER VARCHAR(04),
    FLIGHT_DATE DATETIME,
    DEPARTURE_CITY VARCHAR(03),
    DEPARTURE_TIME DATETIME,
    DEPARTURE_TIME_LOCAL TIME(00),
    ARRIVAL_CITY VARCHAR(03),
    ARRIVAL_TIME DATETIME,
    ARRIVAL_TIME_LOCAL TIME(00),
    OPERATING_DAY VARCHAR(01),
    ONWARD_FLIGHT_NUMBER VARCHAR(04)
)
END 

INSERT INTO TBL_OPERATION_BY_DAY

SELECT 
    A.AIRLINE_CODE,
    A.FLIGHT_NUMBER,
    B.PKDate AS FLIGHT_DATE,
    A.DEPARTURE_CITY,
    A.DEPARTURE_TIME,
    CAST(A.DEPARTURE_TIME AS TIME(0)) AS DEPARTURE_TIME_LOCAL,
    A.ARRIVAL_CITY,
    A.ARRIVAL_TIME,
    CAST(A.ARRIVAL_TIME AS TIME(0)) AS ARRIVAL_TIME_LOCAL,
    A.OPERATING_DAY,
    ONWARD_FLIGHT_NUMBER

FROM 
    TBL_DAYS B
    INNER JOIN
    TBL_FLIGHT_DATA_TULO A ON
    B.PKDATE >= A.FLIGHT_START_DATE AND
    B.PKDATE <= A.FLIGHT_END_DATE AND
    B.CALENDAR_DAY_IN_WEEK = A.OPERATING_DAY


ALTER TABLE TBL_OPERATION_BY_DAY
DROP COLUMN DEPARTURE_TIME, ARRIVAL_TIME
```

Comment: Apart from your problem, I would like to know why are you recreating the table everytime? What situation did force you to do this?

Comment: Based it off some other similar procedures we have. Would it be best to just clear it each time and then insert?

Comment: And why do you create two columns, populate them with data and then immediately drop those columns? Just skip those two columns in the insert.

Comment: Yeah if you just want to re populate the table with new data, then you can just delete all the records or can truncate the table and then insert the data.

Comment: Thanks all. I just truncated it and eliminated the columns that I had dropped. Much better.